# I get null fields when I try to deserialize JSON with GSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

**The Gist**

I tried to deserialize some JSON text with GSON. The JSON string had values defined. However, the deserialized string has null values.

**Exactly what I did**

I tried to deserialize some JSON text with GSON

`SomeSpec deserializedJson = GSON.fromJson(serializedJson, SomeSpec.class);`

where `serializedJson` is a string containing

```
{
    "some_class": "abc.def.SomeClass",
    "stuff": [
        "FOO",
        "BAR",
    ],
    "definition": {
        "values": [
            { "feature": "FOO",    "value": 1.0 },
            { "feature": "BAR",    "value": 1.0 },
        ]
    }
}
```

and `SomeSpec` is a java class containing:

```
package somepackagepath;

import java.util.List;

public class SomeSpec {

  private List<FeatureValueSpec> _values;
  private List<String> _postProcessFunctions;

  public List<FeatureValueSpec> getValues() {
    return _values;
  }

  public List<String> getPostProcessFunctions() {
    return _postProcessFunctions;
  }

  public static class FeatureValueSpec {
    private String _feature;
    private float _value;

    public String getFeature() {
      return _feature;
    }

    public float getValue() {
      return _value;
    }

  }

}
```

The deserialized object had only null fields even though the JSON clearly had those fields defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: There are two errors in your JSON in Arrays. There are extra commas at end of each array.

Second your models should look like this

```
public class Values
{
    private String value;

    private String feature;

    public String getValue ()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getFeature ()
    {
        return feature;
    }

    public void setFeature (String feature)
    {
        this.feature = feature;
    }
}

public class Definition
{
    private Values[] values;

    public Values[] getValues ()
    {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues (Values[] values)
    {
        this.values = values;
    }
}

public class MyPojo
{
    private Definition definition;

    private String[] stuff;

    private String some_class;

    public Definition getDefinition ()
    {
        return definition;
    }

    public void setDefinition (Definition definition)
    {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public String[] getStuff ()
    {
        return stuff;
    }

    public void setStuff (String[] stuff)
    {
        this.stuff = stuff;
    }

    public String getSome_class ()
    {
        return some_class;
    }

    public void setSome_class (String some_class)
    {
        this.some_class = some_class;
    }
}
```